# how to return value from onTap function in flutter

Tags: flutter, function, dart

I am new to programming and flutter.
I am facing an error while returning a value from the onTap function.
The error says The return type 'int' isn't a 'void', as required by the closure's context.
I am getting images from API and showing them on a screen. I want that when someone clicks on an image, the image id should be stored in a variable that will be used on another screen. I am using Gesturedetector's onTap function to get the image id and I am successful to print that id into the terminal and store it in a variable but I am unable to return that variable and want to use that variable on another screen. Anyone, please help me to return the value of that variable. My code is below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Service.dart';
import 'View2.dart';
import 'models/memegenetor_model.dart';

class template_view extends StatefulWidget {
  template_view({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<template_view> createState() => _template_viewState();
}

class _template_viewState extends State<template_view> {
  late Future<Memes_Model> futureScore;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureScore = ApiService().GetTemplates();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder<Memes_Model>(
        future: futureScore,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.data.memes.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 20),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        //height: 100,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap:  (){
                            int tempid=snapshot.data!.data.memes[index].id;
                            return tempid;

                          },
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Image.network(
                                  "${snapshot.data!.data.memes[index].url}",
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2),

                            ],
                          ),
                        )),
                  );
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('${snapshot.error}');
          }

          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return a value from `onTap`. Create a new state in your class.

```dart
class _template_viewState extends State<template_view> {
  int? tempid = null; // or int tempid = -1;
  
  // ...
}
```

`onTap` should look like this:

```dart
onTap: () {
  tempid = snapshot.data!.data.memes[index].id; // use setState if require
},
```